# Rasterio.features.rasterize

Tags: ndvi, rasterio

I have to transform the list of polygons that is in vector form into a raster mask that should be geographically aligned with the NDVI image that I have. I was advised to use `rasterio.features.rasterize`. But I am not sure how to use the function.

Comment: The rasterio docs are unfortunately not building on readthedocs at the moment, but you can find the same info in the [docstring for rasterize](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/features.py#L176-L224).  Post any code you've tried if you need more specific help.

Comment: I don't really understand what the arguments should be. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer elaborating a bit

Answer (score 5):

```
shapes : iterable of (geometry, value) pairs or iterable over
    geometries. `geometry` can either be an object that implements
    the geo interface or GeoJSON-like object.
```

A list, tuple, or generator of shapely geometries (or other GeoJSON-y objects as described, but shapely is easy).  If you want them to be burnt in with the same `default_value`, then this is all you need in the list.  If you have a specific value to burn for each geometry, then your list needs to pair the value with the geometry.  e.g. `[(geom0, 10), (geom1, 20), (geom2, 33)]`.  Sounds like you want a boolean raster, so just supply the geometries here (no pairs).

```
out_shape : tuple or list with 2 integers
    Shape of output numpy ndarray.
```

This should be the shape of the numpy array to be created.  If `source_raster` is the handle returned by `rasterio.open()`, then the shape will be `(source_raster.height, source_raster.width)` (row-major since it's a numpy array).

```
fill : int or float, optional
    Used as fill value for all areas not covered by input
    geometries.
```

Whatever background/nodata value you want.  Sounds like you either want 1 or 0.

```
out : numpy ndarray, optional
    Array of same shape and data type as `source` in which to store
    results.
```

You don't need this unless you want to store the results in an existing array to save memory

```
transform : Affine transformation object, optional
    Transformation from pixel coordinates of `source` to the
    coordinate system of the input `shapes`. See the `transform`
    property of dataset objects.
```

This should be `source_raster.transform`

```
all_touched : boolean, optional
    If True, all pixels touched by geometries will be burned in.  If
    false, only pixels whose center is within the polygon or that
    are selected by Bresenham's line algorithm will be burned in.
```

As described

```
merge_alg : MergeAlg, optional
    Merge algorithm to use.  One of:
        MergeAlg.replace (default): the new value will overwrite the
            existing value.
        MergeAlg.add: the new value will be added to the existing raster.
```

As described, for a mask you'll want the default

```
default_value : int or float, optional
    Used as value for all geometries, if not provided in `shapes`.
```

If you have a single value to burn in, supply it here.  Otherwise you'll have to have specified this within `shapes`.  Since you want a boolean raster, use 1 or 0.

```
dtype : rasterio or numpy data type, optional
    Used as data type for results, if `out` is not provided.
```

I think this should default to something appropriate based on the burn value(s).  If not, use the smallest numpy dtype appropriate for what you've supplied. gdal doesn't like bitmasks, though, so for a boolean raster use `np.uint8`

See the official examples here: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/features.html

Comment: Thank you for the help! 
I have a list of polygons that I had to convert it to NDVI image. Now I am not sure what list to use for the shapes. Also I was advised to use `rasterio.transform.from_bounds` to get an Affine function as a parameter for `transform` in the rasterize one. This part is very confusing. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I'm confused, what do you have as polygons?  If you have an NDVI image and want to apply the polygons as a mask, use the transform and array shape from the NDVI image.  That way your output "polygon mask" array will match the NDVI raster.  The transform essentially maps the world coordinates from the geometry onto the array.  You could use `from_bounds` as well, but if you want what I think you do then you already have the transform available when reading the NDVI raster.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I will write what I did to get the NDVI image in my question so you can see how I did it. And in the next step my taks says: In this step you have to transform the list of polygons, which is currently in vector form, into
a raster mask, which should be geographically aligned with the NDVI image. By doing so you
will be able to tell which pixels from NDVI image belong to which polygon.

Comment: And the hint for this was: For rasterization use `rasterio.features.rasterize` function from `rasterio` Python
package. For function’s parameter `transform` use an instance of `affine.Affine` class which is
returned by `rasterio.transform.from_bounds` function.

Comment: I am confused myself because I am new in this and don't exactly understand the task.